# Spring MongoRepository custom query

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongorepository

Hi I am new to using Spring with MongoRepository and I'm working on creating a custom query for MongoDB using Spring's MongoRepository.
What I would like to do is return a custom query for another variable in my model instead of the Object id.

for my model I have:

```
@Document(collection = "useraccount")
public class UserAccounts {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String accountNumber;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // getters and setters
}
```

inside of my repository I just extend the generic MongoRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserAccountsRepository extends MongoRepository<UserAccounts, String> {


}
```

I am trying to create a custom query that returns the accountNumber inside of my UserAccountsService:

```
@Service
public class UserAccountsService {

    private final UserAccountsRepository userAccountsRepository;

    public UserAccountsService(UserAccountsRepository userAccountsRepository) {
       this.userAccountsRepository = userAccountsRepository;
    }

    // generic find by Object id
    public UserAccounts findOne(String id) {
    Optional<UserAccounts> userAccountsOptional = 
        userAccountsRepository.findById(id);
        if(!userAccountsOptional.isPresent()) {
           throw new RuntimeException("User Account Not Found");
        }

        return userAccountsOptional.get();
    }

    // would like to implement custom query to return UserAccount if 
    // found by accountNumber variable
    public UserAccounts findOneByUserAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {

          return dormantAccountsRepository.findOne(*need query here*);;
      }
}
```

How would I go about creating a custom query to find a User Account by the accountNumber instead of the object id?

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: You don't need to implement any custom methods. These kind of queries are supported out of box. For you case add the method in  `UserAccounts findFirstByAccountNumber(String accountNumber)`  in `UserAccountsRepository`. More [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries)

Comment: thanks I have added that but what would I do to find the account and return it inside of the UserAccountService class?

Comment: Yw. Call the repo as you would do for any queries. `public UserAccounts findOneByUserAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
return userAccountsRepository.findFirstByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
      }`

Comment: @Veeram Humm sorry to bother but it does not seem to be able to find the accountNumber variable from the model.  how does userAccountsRepository.findFirstByAccountNumber(accountNumber) know it needs to find accountNumber from the model? i keep getting a 500 error from this return type. thanks for the help thus far

Comment: Looking at the `findOneByUserAccountNumber(String accountNumber)` the account number is passed outside of service, so I;m not sure what you refer when you say _how does userAccountsRepository.findFirstByAccountNumber(accountNumber) know it needs to find accountNumber from the model?_ . The account number is passed from service to repository.

Comment: it works thank you soo much for your help I was just having a uri issue what you have is corrent!